# Какие веб-технологии использовать для создания калькулятора с 3D элементами?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, flash, 3d

Вот есть флешовый калькулятор (или конструктор) каких-то коробок - http://www.packaging-works.co.uk/BoxDesigner

**Вопрос:** какие веб-технологии, кроме флеша, наиболее преимущественно использовать для создания такого чуда? И чтобы на планшетах тоже работало.

Comment: [Например][1]


  [1]: http://www.linux.org.ru/news/internet/10359826

Comment: Если не flash, то unity3D.